# XAML Pivot Headerless

Tags: xaml, pivot, uwp

I am loocking to change my pivot style to get no empty space in the headers.

Here is a pic of my page:

[image]

Blue part is a control header from template10.

White part is the height of empty space from pivot header.

Green part are a commands bars (this is inside the pivot).

I cant use negative margin in the pivot because my pageheader contains a secundary menu, and this result blocked.

I have write a style to set the height of the pivot header without good results.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="PivotHeaderless" TargetType="PivotItem">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value=""/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>

        <Pivot x:Name="MainPivot">

            <PivotItem Style="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderless}"/>
        </Pivot>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add the tag "Template10" to get better help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/template10

Comment: Template10 is not relevant here, it is mainly about the pivot control template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to make a change in the template of the control itself.

If you navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\<SDKVERSION>\Generic\generic.xaml`, you will find out, that the default template of `Pivot` control contains the following:

```
<PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- ... more code -->
</Grid>
```

The first row of the gird has the height of `Auto`. This means its height is set to accomodate for the contained content. But this header contains not only the header of your pivot item, but also two control buttons for paging - Previ:

```
<Button x:Name="PreviousButton"
Grid.Column="1"
Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}"
Width="20"
Height="36"
... />
<Button x:Name="NextButton"
Grid.Column="1"
Template="{StaticResource PreviousTemplate}"
Width="20"
Height="36"
... />
```

As you can see, the height of these buttons is hardcoded to 36 pixels, which means that no matter what you do, if you don't do something about them, the header will have always at leasst 36 pixels in height.

## Solution

The easiest solution is to create a copy of the default template of the `Pivot` control (for example by copying the `Style` definition from the `generic.xaml` file) and setting the first `Grid`'s row height to 0. This will effectively hide it and make it invisible. To make it even more effective, you can delete all the controls which are in the first row so that they are not constructed and you improve the performance:

```
<PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
<Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>        
    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
    </ItemsPresenter>
</Grid>
</PivotPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to MZetko I found the perfect headerless style, you can use his method yourself or if your prefer only copy the code, here it is:

```
<Style TargetType="Pivot" x:Key="PivotHeaderless">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource PivotBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Pivot">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootElement"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="BaseContentControlStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>

                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TitleContentControl" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource PivotLandscapeThemePadding}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HeaderStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="HeaderDynamic" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="HeaderStatic">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Header" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="StaticHeader" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="TitleContentControl"
                            IsTabStop="False"
                            Margin="{StaticResource PivotPortraitThemePadding}"

                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Title}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" />
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1">

                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle"
                                HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                VerticalSnapPointsType="None"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                Template="{StaticResource ScrollViewerScrollBarlessTemplate}"
                                BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False">
                                <!---->
                                    <PivotPanel x:Name="Panel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <Grid x:Name="PivotLayoutElement">
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="PivotLayoutElementTranslateTransform" />
                                            </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="LeftHeaderPresenter"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding LeftHeader}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding LeftHeaderTemplate}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper"
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            UseSystemFocusVisuals="True"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                                                <ContentControl.Clip>
                                                    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="HeaderClipperGeometry" />
                                                </ContentControl.Clip>
                                                <Grid Background="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderBackground}">
                                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderOffsetTranslateTransform" />
                                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="StaticHeader" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                        <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="StaticHeaderTranslateTransform" />
                                                        </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                                    <PivotHeaderPanel x:Name="Header">
                                                        <PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                            <CompositeTransform x:Name="HeaderTranslateTransform" />
                                                        </PivotHeaderPanel.RenderTransform>
                                                    </PivotHeaderPanel>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ContentControl>


                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="RightHeaderPresenter"
                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding RightHeader}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding RightHeaderTemplate}"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                                <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TransformGroup>
                                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform" />
                                                    </TransformGroup>
                                                </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                            </ItemsPresenter>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </PivotPanel>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```